# How to configure the jQuery UI Datepicker to use a localized calendar?

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm wondering if this is possible and if yes, how would I go about doing it? I'm trying to make the widget use a Jalali(Persian) Calender.

Answer (score 2):

**jQuery UI Datepicker localization**

In general, to add localization to jQuery UI Datepicker you need to include a specific localization file immediately after including the Datepicker's script. For example, to set a French localization, you'd do this:

```
[...include jQuery and jQuery UI...]
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js"></script>
```

The localization files are included as part of the the standard [jQuery UI download](http://jqueryui.com/download/), in a separate directory (`development-bundle/ui/i18n`). For more on this, see the [Datepicker API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) (under "Localization").

**Current status: Farsi in, Jalali out**

Currently, jQuery UI download package doesn't seem to include a Jalali localization file. For now, there seems to be only a regular (Georgian) calendar translated into Farsi (`jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js`).

**Solution 1 - custom localization file**

If you prefer to stick with jQuery UI's datepicker, you can create a custom localization file, based on the format of existing localization files. If you're familiar with the calendar in question, it shouldn't be difficult.

**Solution 2 - use a different plugin**

Consider using the [jQuery Calendars plugin](http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html) instead. It already includes most common world calendars in [several languages and formats](http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html#l10n), so generating a Jalali or any other foreign calendar for that matter is done by the flick of a setting.

Answer (score 0):

Might be too late, but since I stumbled on it, here is a demo someone has been kind enough to put up. All credits to unknown author
http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.6rc5/demos/datepicker/localization.html